# Limit identical input in database to a certain count

Tags: mysql, database

I know that we can limit an identical input in database to only one by the keyword UNIQUE, but how about limiting it to more than one? For example, 3,4? Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way is to do it on your way by checking that amount before doing a new insert.

Before insert a new row, check how many identical rows there are and handle that case (e.g. don't perform the insert and/or show a message to the user).